# How to estimate the sine function with "parameters" using DNN in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

What I wanted to do is estimating sine function with parameters like frequency w, time t, phase phi.

There are two cases I tried.(I attached links for the description picture and source codes below)

Case 1 is about estimation of the sine function with single input x
Case 2 is about estimation of the sine function with multi inputs(x is divided by 3 : frequency w, time t, phase phi)

Case 1 works well. I got very low loss value.(approximately 0)
Case 2 doesn't work well. loss value is quite high. It converges to 25

I want to improve its performance and know the reason why it has a poor performance.

I attached nbviewer links for the source codes and the evernote link for the description picture.

Case 1) https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/nuriahn/1dd28ef1164a8a358bb7875f48dc1174

Case 2)
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/nuriahn/f4b25917243c4b043caf640362dcd0ea

Description picture)
http://www.evernote.com/l/AYuq8O7ErDtKK4346xKk7RzmVx9fX0zTdT8/

I expect this model can learn this formula : y=sin(w*t+phi). 
For example, when I put w=2, t=4 and phi=0.5 as inputs then I get the output y as the result of sin(2*4+0.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, only case 1 will work as it is considering w and phi as parameters to learn.

In the second case, you cannot expect the network to learn as you are passing parameters (which are supposed to be learnt by network) as inputs and letting network determine the relationship between them through fully connected layers (by adding more weights).

Comment: Could you explain for me why second case is hard so that I can modify the second source code?

Comment: According to me, rather than hard it’s impossible. The network not just learns the relationship between variables but also adds multiple weight parameters in the existing w, t and phi. In addition to that, conceptually also it doesn’t sound the bell. Sine wave is supposed to be a function of time only. But you are trying to make it a function of time, frequency and phase. Possibly you may have some explanation for this way of implementation.